# How to get deleted object information from association relation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have 3 tables, Teacher/Int_Teacher_Student/Student, here is the schema:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = 'teacher_table'
   has_many :teacher_students, primary_key: :teacher_id, foreigh_key: :int_teacher_id, dependent: destroy
   has_many :students, through :teacher_students

class TeacherStudent <ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name= 'int_teacher_student'
   belongs_to :teacher, primary_key: :teacher_id, foreign_key: :int_teacher_id, touch: true
   belongs_to :student, primary_key: :student_id, foreign_key: :int_student_id, touch: true

 class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = 'int_student'
   has_many :teacher_students, primary_key: :student_id, foreigh_key: :int_student_id, dependent: destroy
   has_many :teachers, through :teacher_students
```

I have a task to show teacher name after either teacher or student record changed.

I have some code in Teacher class:

```
   def print_teacher_name
       puts "teacher name #{self.name}"
   end
```

And in Student class:

```
 after_commit :print_teacher_name 
  def  print_teacher_name
       self.teachers.each do |teacher|
          teacher.print_teacher_name
       end
  end
```

And in TeacherStudent class:

```
  after_commit :print_teacher_name 
  def  print_teacher_name
       self.teacher.print_teacher_name
  end
```

When a student or teacher deleted, or when a teacher added to a student, this works fine. But when a teacher removed from a student, the call doesn't fire. Looks to me that the print_teacher_name in TeacherStudent class didn't get fired for such situation, but I do see that the record removed from that table. Anyone can give me some idea what I can try to resolve this? Thanks.